# WebdriverIO version 7, using @cucumber/cucumber v7, using junit v7, the count of tests is not updating

Tags: jenkins, junit, cucumber, webdriver-io

Upgraded to Version 7 for WebdriverIO. In the process upgraded the cucumber framework as well to ver 7
"@wdio/cucumber-framework":"^7.0.7",

After upgrading noticed that the test counts are not updating. Unable to use junit reports with Jenkins.

I could only get it to work if I downgraded cucumber from version 7 to 6. Using 6.11.1 and it works fine now.

Anyone facing same issue?

Bit surprising on the official page also - the test counts are showing 0 for examples.
tests="0" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0"

Am I missing something here?

https://webdriver.io/docs/junit-reporter/

Comment: hmm perhaps do a full update of all dependencies..

Comment: I have done that as I delete workspaces/builds and force clone repos on Jenkins and fresh npm installs, no luck.